# Need help debugging a function which updates binary files

Tags: c++, debugging, binaryfiles

```
void updatebfile(char filename[MAX])
{

fstream writereadb;

char cont='y';
char filenameb [MAX];
int i=1;
int record;

student s;

strcpy(filenameb,filename);
strcat(filenameb,".dat");

writereadb.open(filenameb,ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary  );


cout<<"------------------------------"
    <<endl;

cout<<"Begin updating of binary file "
    <<filenameb
    <<endl
    <<endl;

cout<<"Information for student file"
    <<endl
    <<endl;


while ( writereadb.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&s), sizeof (s) ) )
{

    cout<<i
        <<'\t'
        <<s.identity
        <<" "
        <<s.name
        <<endl;

    i++;


}
writereadb.clear();

do
{   
cout<<endl
    <<"Update record: ";
cin>>record;

cout<<endl
    <<"Student id: ";   

writereadb.seekg ( (record - 1) * sizeof(s), ios::beg);
writereadb.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&s), sizeof (s));    

cout<<s.identity
    <<endl; 

cout<<"Update the name: "; 
cin.getline(s.name,50); //My programme does not stop at this line to read in an input for some reason
//cin.clear();
    //cin.ignore(200,'\n'); 

writereadb.seekp((record-1)*sizeof(student),ios::beg);  
writereadb.write (reinterpret_cast <const char *>(&s), sizeof (s));

cout<<"Any more update (y/n) :";
cin>>cont;//

}while (cont=='y');

writereadb.close();
 }
```

My program works fine except towards the end of the program when it encounters the `cin.getline(s.name,50)`. The programme does not stop to read in an input and continues running.

I have tried putting `cin.clear(); cin.ignore;` after the `cin.getline(s.name,50)`, it works but it doesn't store the `s.name` into binary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `cin.ignore();` 
just right before `cin.getline(s.name,50);`

Comment: ignore doesnt work as it only ignores 1 character, you have to use cin.ignore(200,'\n') Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have to add

> cin.clear();
>
> cin.ignore(200,'\n');

to clear the '\n' from using the >> operator during cin>>